# Magento “Sort By filter ” is not displaying correct information

Tags: magento-1.7, filter

Magento My Sort By filter is not displaying correct information for example

My Sort By “sale” is bringing up items that aren’t on sale. Any idea?

Do I have to have a start and end date on each for them to work?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is "sale"? And I'm sure whatever you are talking about, there is no start and end date on any attribute you can sort by :)

Comment: Did you try and refresh your indexes?

Comment: Can send me url ? I have aleady fixed this kind of issue . Some i have fixed through admin setting .

Answer (score 1):

okay I think I figured out why this was happening. We have a Catalog Price Rule for certain items and it seems like those items effected are the ones that don’t have the “sale” icon. Which is what was throwing me off. All the items that were marked as special price have fancy sales icons. All the products that are being discounted due to the catalog price rule do not. I was getting confused because I was thinking the items werent on sale when they were. Does anyone know  anyway I can make it so the “sale” and the items with Catalog Price Rule both have this icon? Thanks